# Migrating from a Mongoose Model to Postgres NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, mongoose, bookshelf.js

I have a node project which I use twillo to verify Phone number and it works with MongoDB, now I want to transfer the same logic to an old project which uses Posgres and Bookshelf to create tables, I have tried adding the necessary fields and but it does not reflect in the database as I would want it to, and How to effectively write methods with the Bookshelf model. Below is my postgres code and my Mongo model that works which I want to replicate with postgres

```
const UserSchemax = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  countryCode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  verified: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  authyId: String,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
// Middleware executed before save - hash the user's password
UserSchemax.pre('save', function (next) {
  const self = this;
  // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
  if (!self.isModified('password')) return next();
  // generate a salt
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    // hash the password using our new salt
    bcrypt.hash(self.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
      self.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
// Test candidate password
UserSchemax.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
  const self = this;
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, self.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};
// Send a verification token to this user
UserSchemax.methods.sendAuthyToken = function (cb) {
  var self = this;
  if (!self.authyId) {
    // Register this user if it's a new user
    authy.register_user(self.email, self.phone, self.countryCode,
      function (err, response) {
        if (err || !response.user) return cb.call(self, err);
        self.authyId = response.user.id;
        self.save(function (err, doc) {
          if (err || !doc) return cb.call(self, err);
          self = doc;
          sendToken();
        });
      });
  } else {
    // Otherwise send token to a known user
    sendToken();
  }
  // With a valid Authy ID, send the 2FA token for this user
  function sendToken() {
    authy.request_sms(self.authyId, true, function (err, response) {
      cb.call(self, err);
    });
  }
};
// Test a 2FA token
UserSchemax.methods.verifyAuthyToken = function (otp, cb) {
  const self = this;
  authy.verify(self.authyId, otp, function (err, response) {
    cb.call(self, err, response);
  });
};
```

here is my current Postgres model

```
const User = models.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    uuid: true,

    schema: [
        fields.StringField('first_name'),
        fields.StringField('last_name'),
        fields.StringField('photo'),
        fields.StringField('phone'),
        fields.EmailField('email'),
        fields.BooleanField('verified')
        fields.StringField('authyId')
        fields.EncryptedStringField('password', {
            min_length: {
                value: 8,
                message: '{{label}} must be at least 8 characters long!'
            }
        }),
        fields.BooleanField('old_account')
    ]}
```

I just added the `authyId` and `verified` fields and still, they do not reflect in my postgres table. further code would be supplied on request, I am equally new to NodeJS

Comment: Bookshelf doesn't know about your database schema. Where did you get the `schema` property from?

Comment: That is a mongose schema. I am trying to replicate this in postgres database

Comment: Bookshelf doesn't need to know your schema to fetch, save and delete things, so your problem seems to be that you're expecting the models to automatically change the database to always match what they specify as schema. AFAIK there is no ORM with Postgres support for Node.js that does that. You have to use database migrations for that. Example: https://knexjs.org/#Migrations